# What is the best way to initialize data by JPA?

Tags: java, maven, jpa

Does anyone initialize data by putting some code to static constructor of some initailizing class or something like that? I wonder where is posibillity like this:

```
@EJB //some bean
public someDataClassOrFacade {
  static {
    if(DataFacade.checkIfThereIsNoExampleData()) {
     SomeDataClass sdc = new SomeDataClass();
     // (...) set data
     DataFacade.create(sdc);
    }
   }
}
```

What do you think about this way to initialize data? I am not convinced about using SQL queries with maven SQL plugin, because it has low flexibility (assuming data structure can change, especially columns names). But, i not pretty sure when class will be loaded. But this is only my theoretical practice, maybe you're using something far better than that? Thanks.

Comment: SomeDataClass' constructor is where I'd put such code.

Comment: Ok, but where i have to invoke constructor? I mean, where i need to trigger this class to initialize before my business logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to initialize the data as late as possible and in a controlled moment in my opinion, so static initializers are a no-no for me. It depends on what type of application it is where I would do the initialization. If there is a web layer I would probably do it with a web framework specific initialization method or with a servlet context listener. If there is only an EJB layer, I might do it in a singleton EJB annotated with @Startup as this thread I quick-googled shows:

[EJB stateless - Private members initialisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847853/ejb-stateless-private-members-initialisation)

Comment: If you don't want to tie it to an application container, JPA can also be used outside of the container.  So a straight Java class could be run from the command line without requiring it to be tied to the application expecting the data as well.

Comment: I will try, you're right about using singleton with @Startup annotation, but before i make this answer as a solution i would check this out. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I'd use something like Liquibase instead of an EJB.  It is designed for database management.

Comment: That wasn't the question. The question is how to do this in conjunction with EJB tech.

Comment: Well, maybe i want to, but used technology is off the table, unfortunately.